# I hate that the caller id display moves across screen

Tags: iphone, display

I have an iPhone 6s. Ever since the last update, when I get a call, the caller ID display moves across the screen like a news ticker. Instead of just glancing at it, I now have to wait for the number to complete its movement to see it.  Is there any way to get it back to just appearing all at once so I can see it?

Comment: Wondering if perhaps your text size (Settings > Display & Brigtness) got reset to something quite large. Also if you could post a screen capture to your original question showing the effect that might help.

Answer (score 1):

As of now, on iOS 12.0, this is not something that can be altered. It was part of the update, and it unfortunately does not have a way of being changed back to the original format.

Comment: Thank you!  I'm not happy about it, but I appreciate your providing a definitive answer!